# ShareFile (by Citrix) automate Upload with PowerSHell

Tags: sharefile

It's Aug 2019 and I'm trying to find the way automate Upload of local file to Citrix  ShareFile folder. I installed all updates and `Add-PSSnapin` but still fail to produce any result.  Did anybody succeeded doing this ?
There are some links [here](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2014/05/16/getting-started-with-the-powershell-sdk/)
Below I pasted [(c)](https://github.com/citrix/ShareFile-PowerShell/tree/master/Samples) script that expected to do this. and error I'm getting on first line.

```
Add-PSSnapin ShareFile
################################################################################
# DownloadFiles.ps1
#
# This script will download all files from the My Files and Folders area of 
# ShareFile to the local Documents directory.
#

#Run the following interactively to create a login token that can be used by Get-SfClient in unattended scripts
#$sfClient = New-SfClient -Name ((Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "Documents") + "\YourSubdomain.sfps") -Account YourSubdomain
$sfClient = Get-SfClient -Name ((Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "Documents") + "\YourSubdomain.sfps")

#ShareFile directory is relative to the root of the account
#get the current user's home folder to use as the starting point
$ShareFileHomeFolder = "sfdrive:/" + (Send-SfRequest $sfClient -Entity Items).Name

#use the local My Documents folder
$LocalPath = (Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "Documents")

#Create a PowerShell provider for ShareFile at the location specified
New-PSDrive -Name sfDrive -PSProvider ShareFile -Client $sfClient -Root "/"

#download files from a sub-folder in ShareFile to a local folder
#path must be specified (can't use root) so make sure to map the provider at a level higher than you want to copy from
Copy-SfItem -Path $ShareFileHomeFolder -Destination $LocalPath

#Remove the PSProvider when we are done
Remove-PSDrive sfdrive
```

---

```
PS C:\PSR> Add-PSSnapin ShareFile
Add-PSSnapin : The term 'Add-PSSnapin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin ShareFile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-PSSnapin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

Go here:
https://github.com/citrix/ShareFile-PowerShell/releases

Download and run the installer that matches your version of Operating System (x32 or x64), 64-bit is the most likely correct one.

Make sure that you are running the equivalent version of PowerShell (x32 or x64) because both versions are available on a 64-bit machine. You can run the command `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` to determine if you are running in a 64-bit Powershell or not.

Then run the command: `Add-PSSnapin Sharefile`